# Radiobutton Listでラジオボタンをリストの右側に表示する方法

Tags: onsen-ui, css

Onsen UIのパターンに[Radiobutton List](http://ja.onsen.io/pattern-radiobutton_list.html)がありますが、チェックの表示位置を
iOSのUIに準拠し、右側に表示させたいのです。
その方法をご存知でしたら、ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

クラスを追加してCSSで右側に移動させます。

```
<style>
    .radio-button--right {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
    }
</style>
:
: 省略
:
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
  <label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
    <input type="radio" name="a" checked>
    <div class="radio-button__checkmark radio-button--list-item__checkmark radio-button--right"></div>
    Chrome
  </label>
</ons-list-item>
```

Comment: コメントが遅くなり申し訳ございません。
上記のソースを参考に実装したところ、
チェックマークが右側に表示できました。
ありがとうございます。